# How to Wrap/Unwrap text in Excel in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Please help me to wrap/unwrap text in excel using vb.net with the following code:

Dim excelDoc as stringBuilder
 excelDoc.Append("")
 excelDoc.Append(" " 
                   & "I am Jewel. Bangladesh is my country")
 excelDoc.Append("")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be solved using ss:WrapText=""1"" to wrap and ss:WrapText=""0"" to unwrap which should be use in Alignment like this:

```
<Alignment ss:Horizontal=""Left"" ss:Vertical=""Center"" ss:WrapText=""0""/>
```